# Phonegap AJAX issue

Tags: ajax, cordova

I am stuck trying to make ajax work on phonegap 2.5.0 application with android. Scanned through stackoverflow and google, but nothing seem to help. Please advice.

So, I am just trying to make a simple AJAX GET request like this:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
       var url='http://test.dev/app_dev.php/stuff/add-external?callback=test';
       alert('connecting to '+url);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(res) {
                alert('success:'+res);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
               alert(xhr.status);
              alert(thrownError);
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                alert('complete');
            }
       });
}
```

};

I use jsonp even though it seems not required on phonegap, but helps testing on browser.
So this works when I test with browser: alerts "connecting to url", then "success", then "complete". On phonegap however it just alers "conneting to url" and then nothing.

I added `<access origin="*" />` to config.xml, and also to res/xml/config/xml. Also added these permissions to AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.phonegap.exampleapp" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

This is my res/xml/plugins.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   <plugins>
     <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" /> 
   </plugins>
```

Still not working :(. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: change "this.onDeviceReady" to "app.onDeviceReady" and let us know how it goes.

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly be related, since this method is triggered fine on device. The part which is not working is ajax itself

Comment: I understand that, but you cannot say whether Cordova is actually raising the even or something else is firing. Since app is not an instance object, "this" is pointing to the window object (most likely). Try my suggestion and let us know how it goes.

Comment: thanks for help, I already found the problem (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just realized that the problem was unrelated to the phonegap. I configured proxy to my computer on the phone's wi-fi settings for testing which works fine from mobile browser, but applications seem to ignore this. Thus, when testing it with external url on web, rather than from my local server it worked as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify?

```
$.getJSON('yourtarget.php', function(data) {
  alert("my name is: "+data.name+" !!! ");
});
```

Comment: I am actually trying to make POST request later, just testing GET first for simlicity. Either case it won't work

Comment: strange, it works perfectly for me, might be some version conflict or something i cant see

Comment: sure, my res/xml/config.xml : http://pastebin.com/RYStN2JV , my androidmanifest :  http://pastebin.com/vsRSm2YM

Comment: I tried this, but it did not help. Btw, I did not mention that I am trying to use build.phonegap.com to compile it and using there starter app (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start) as starting point. Is it something different about configs there?

Comment: oh yeah, dunno much about it, but maybe it can be something with it, https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml , check the `Access Element`, might be that

Comment: yes, that is what I am doing as described in my question. Weirdly still cannot make it work